# Azure CosmosDB (SQL) - How to query an for a set of objects with a list to return when any element in the object's list matches condition

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

From the database we need to return all objects who have a closedDate within a date range.  The CloseDate property is on a child object contained in the list within the object.  I want to return the object if any ClosedDate within that list is within the date range.  Currently i'm only able to construct a Cosmos query which returns the object when All CloseDates are in the range but I need to return when Any are in the range.

**Current Query**

```
 IQueryable<ServiceRepairOrder> query = this.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<ServiceRepairOrder>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, ContainerName()), queryOptions)
                .Where(ro => ro.AccountId == this.AccountID)
                .Where(ro => ro.Items.Any(li => li.ClosedDate >= start && li.ClosedDate <= end) );
```

**Object JSON Example**

```
{
    "id": "45144",
    "Type": "ServiceRepairOrder",
    "AccountID": "account1",
    "Items": [
        {
            "ClosedDate": "someDateInRange",
            "Id": "itemId1",
            "Key": "value1"
        },
        {
            "ClosedDate": "someDateOutOfRange",
            "Id": "itemId2",
            "Key": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How about use `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: The `&&` looks correct. But what is the problem exactly? Do you get an exception or do you not get the correct results?

Comment: The problem is the Any is acting like an All.  The result set only includes objects in which all those with Items.Closed date are in the date range.  I want the objects in which any Items.ClosedDate are in the date range

Comment: I have tried your LINQ. It works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?

```
SELECT distinct c.id FROM c JOIN t IN c.Items where t.ClosedDate>="2020-11-1" and t.ClosedDate<="2020-11-30"
```

[image]
[image]